# Composer require gives errors while installing barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I'm quite new with Laravel and wrote my first app.

I'm using Laravel 5.4 with PHP 7.1.5 on Windows, but when I run the `composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` command, I get following issues. I have followed many "possible solutions" but still it is not working.

This is the error:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
> packages.
>
> Problem 1
> - Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-dompdf ^0.8.1 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-dom
> pdf[v0.8.1].
> - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf v0.8.1 requires dompdf/dompdf ^0.8 -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[v0.
> 8.0, v0.8.1, v0.8.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Comment: Check your .lock file, does any of the packages require  dompdf/dompdf version different from [v0. 8.0, v0.8.1, v0.8.2]?

Comment: where can i find the composer.lock file

Comment: i found it and yes my dompdf/dompdf is version 0.7.0 
how can i update it?

Comment: Looks like some of your dependencies require 0.7.0 version. You should find which one and deal with it.

Answer (score 6):

Don't `composer update`. If you have `dompdf/dompdf` in your composer.json just update it, specifying `0.8.*` as version and running

`composer update dompdf/dompdf`

then

`composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`

--

Running a generic `composer update` will affect all your other dependencies you may want keep as they currently are.

All the changes affected by your `composer update` command are then recorded in your composer.lock file.

When you'll move your project somewhere else or you'll deploy it on a server for example, the `composer install` command will read the composer.lock file and will install the exact version of your dependencies which are recorded in it. So you'll be sure about the version of your dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

Run this command
`composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf  "^0.8.2"` .

Comment: answer is worked for me, Thank you. 
**** composer update ******* then ****** composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf  "^0.8.2"******

Answer (score 1):

Delete your `composer.lock` file and run:

```
composer install
```

Comment: where can i find the composer.lock file

Comment: @FrankoHysaj in your project directory

Comment: @Good answer, Sort and simple . Thanks

Comment: composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf  "^0.8.2"

Answer (score 0):

Check then `dompdf/dompdf` may updated e.g. `0.7.*` or `~0.7.0`

```
composer update;
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf;
```