# Cannot install barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I could not install `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` using `composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`.

The error I got was:

> [Invalid argument exception] Could not find a matching version of barryvdh/laravel-dompdf. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (dev).

So in order to fix the error, I included `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf: master@dev` in composer.json and did a `composer update`. This time it gave me the error:

> The requested package barryvdh/laravel-dompdf could not be found in any version. there may be a typo in the package name

Below is my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "master@dev"
    },
    "repositories":
    [
        {
          "type": "composer",
          "url": "https:\/\/www.phpclasses.org\/"
        },
        {
          "packagist": false
        }
    ],
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "app/includes",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

What do you think I am missing here?

Comment: "master@dev" may not be exist in versions list.Try "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.3" in composer.json and then composer update

Comment: yes, i thought the same and had tried `^0.8.3` which is the supported version for laravel 5.7, but it gives the same warning `The requested package barryvdh/laravel-dompdf could not be found in any version. there may be a typo in the package name`.

Comment: Please refer : https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/119

Comment: tried these as well. but this looks like a different issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301899/composer-require-gives-errors-while-installing-barryvdh-laravel-dompdf

Comment: run ``Composer diagnose`` to find issue

Comment: Hey, i removed the repositories section from the composer.json and the package got installed. Thank you for your time taken in researching for a solution. i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, it is advisable not to edit `composer.json` directly when installing third-party packages. You can remove the line `"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "master@dev"` from your file, and run this command from your project root directory instead:

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

It installs the latest stable third-party package and automatically updates both `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files.

UPDATE: To solve the problem with your `composer.json`file, change the repositories key to this:

```
"repositories" : 
[
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packagist.org"
    },
    {
        "packagist": false
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.4",
```

instead of

```
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "master@dev"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line in your `composer.json` file

```
"require": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "master@dev"
},
```

After, run this command in your command prompt

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

This will download the package and the dompdf + fontlib libraries also. This will generate the latest version for your project

Please Check this: [barryvdh/laravel-dompdf](https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)

Answer (score 0):

The package got installed after removing the repositories section from my composer.json.

Thank you all for the help

Comment: @UdoE. i don't want others checking this thread to be misguided as the answers don't rectify my situation in relation to my `composer.json` file. i will be open to accept my answer after a day more.

Comment: Ok. Check and test my updated answer. I didn't notice the problem with your repositories key until now